# How do I enable these two gesture features in Trading View library like in their app?

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, touch-event, tradingview-api

I want to enable these two features in the Trading view library, I'm integrating it in my Android project.

1. I want to show that box with (price information, date etc) when you hold down your finger on the chart in the first pic.
2. When you hold down two fingers, it highlights the chart in between that area in the second pic.
   They are present in their TradingView app,

[image: First Pic]
[image: Second Pic]

I would appreciate any help. I went through their whole feature list [TradingView feature list](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/customization/Featuresets) and tried enabling most of them but no success and at this point I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Check this for your first question:
https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tradingview/lightweightcharts/example/app/view/charts/CustomTooltipFragment.kt#L110
If you find the answer to the second one, let me know.

Comment: You can use MPChartAndroid for custom chart and gesture follow the link

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart#gesture-callbacks